# Are boolean variables typically implemented as single bits?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, compiler-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One-byte bool. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220726/one-byte-bool-why)

I want to add a boolean variable to a class. However, this class is pretty size-sensitive, and as a result I'm loath to add another field. However, it is composed of a pile of members that are at least a `char` wide, and a single other `bool`.

If I were hand-writing this code, I would implement those boolean fields as bits in the last byte or so of the object. Since accesses have to be byte-aligned, this would cause no spacial overhead.

Now, do compilers typically do this trick? The only reason I can of for them not to is because it would involve an additional mask to get that bit out of there.

Comment: Use `std::bitset` if you care about size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, compilers can't do this trick because the address of each member has to be distinct. If you want to pack a fixed number of bits, use `std::bitset`. If you need a variable number of bits use `boost::dynamic_bitset`.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't know of any compilers which optimize a bool down to a bit.

You can force this behavior via:

```
unsigned int m_firstBit : 1;
unsigned int m_secondBit : 1;
unsigned int m_thirdBit : 1;
```

As for reasons why not, it would likely violate some language guarantees. For instance, you couldn't pass `&myBool` to a function which takes a `bool*` if it doesn't have its own reserved byte.

Comment: Of course, `: 1` is only going to work in bitfields.

Comment: Well, he said it was already in a class, so he ought to be able to use the bitfield trick.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers typically do not do that, but you could use `std::bitset<2>` to pack two bools into one byte.